# Why there is two way to navigate between fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-framelayout

When I'm learning to navigate between fragment, I have found two ways to do that. One of them is using Navigation Host

```
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(destination)
```

and of them using FrameLayout

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply{
    replace(flFragment,destination)
    commit()
}
```

Is there any differences between two of them? If not, what are the differences and which one is better?
Tq in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SupportFragmentManager & FragmentManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager) are relatively old ways of navigating an user through different fragments. They were widely used before, but have some drawbacks like:

- Hard backstack navigation
- Problems with adding or removing fragments, etc.

The [Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation) component is part of [Android Jetpack](https://developer.android.com/jetpack). It's a new approach and it aims to simplify and solve some of the problems related to the old one described above. Also, it is not restricted to work only with Fragments.